# Mimicking a login form...

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, autologin

We have an internal application that requires the same username/password across the board.

However, if the login fails too many times, then the account is locked for that username.

We can't change the lockout because that will affect the public facing site as well.

I have been asked to come up with a way to essentially, click a button and auto-login.

**Initial research has brought me to this script...** ([Credit](http://happy-snail.webs.com/autologinintogames.htm))

```
<!doctype html>
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->

    <html>
    <title>Auto Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post"    action="http://mail.google.com">
    <select name="uni_url" id="logServer" class="validate[required]">
    <option  class=""  value="" fbUrl=""  cookieName=""  >
            Test_en
    </option>
    </select>
    <input id="loginName" name="name" type="text" value="Username" class="" />
    <input id="loginPassword" name="password" type="password" value="ExamplePassword" class="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="loginKid" name="kid" value=""/>
                        </form>
  <script>document.loginForm.submit();</script>       
  </body></html>
```

**...but I can't seem to get it to work for me.**

So, I found another option where I can create a small html file (form) with a submit button, that does - `onload="form1.submit();"`, and this could basically log me into this website without having to key in any login information.

Not sure where to start with mimicking a login form like this and need a good direction to get started in.

Thoughts?

Comment: "I can't seem to get it to work for me." >> What doesn't work?

Comment: Sounds like greasemonkey user-script time to me. Set the values, submit the form, and away you go

Comment: @gvee I can't seem to get the values correct. There are a lot of hidden values and they're confusing me. I just want the username/password to populate in the fields when the button click event happens.

Comment: Here's the website [**here**](https://mycampus.southuniversity.edu/portal/server.pt). See if you can get it to populate a test username/password...

Comment: Using JS: `document.getElementById('pt-login-username-textbox').value = "Yay!";`

Comment: Alternatively modify the source code: `<input type="text" alt="ptmsgs_portalbrowsingmsgs string 633" size="30" class="formInputBoxText" name="in_tx_username" id="pt-login-username-textbox" onkeypress="return executeViaEnter(event);" value="**YAY**">`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your existing login form looks like this:

```
<form action="/login.php" method="post" id="loginform">
    <input type="text"     name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

On your "auto-login" (which is really an *auto-submit*) page you want to mimic the same structure as before but:

- Add in values to be submitted (static username and password?)
- Optionally remove the submit button (if you **know** your users have JS enabled then you can get rid).
- Add some JS that automagically submits the form for you.

That might give us something like this:

```
<form action="/login.php" method="post" id="loginform">
    <input type="text"     name="username" value="gvee" />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="hunter2" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].submit()</script>
```

The javascript will essentially look for the first form on the page (`forms[0]`) and submit that.

---

## Update

Upon further inspection your existing login form is a bit of a funny onion. Instead of submitting the form directly, it's calling a function called `doLogin()` that sets certain hidden properties.

Therefore, instead of submitting the form, we should mimic the same behaviour (i.e. call `doLogin()` instead of `.submit()`).

One key thing here is that you'll want to only call the function after it has been declared. Simplest solution is to put our added bit of script at the very bottom of the HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">doSubmit();</script>
```

Comment: I used your idea. It redirects to the site properly, but it's not filling in the information... here's how my form looks... `<form action="https://mycampus.southuniversity.edu/portal/server.pt" method="post" name="LoginPortletForm" id="loginFormID">
    <input type="text"     name="in_tx_username" value="gvee" />
    <input type="password" name="in_pw_userpass" value="hunter2" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].submit()</script>`

Comment: Aha! Upon further digging your website doesn't actually submit the form in a standard way. Instead the "Log in" button executes a JS function: `doLogin()` (found in the `server.pt` file)

Comment: So, would that bottom `<script>` line look like this `<script type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].doLogin()</script>`?

Comment: @webfrogs not quite... Try just `doLogin()` on it's own... but you'll have to place that script at the end of the page (after the `doLogin()` function is actually declared)

Comment: I uploaded this form (what I have up to now) [**here**](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/login1.html). Is this where I should be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37190/discussion-between-gvee-and-webfrogs)